# MongoDB atlas error: uncaughtException: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I am new to mongodb please excuse my language.
I have deployed backend of the application to heroku and tring to connect it with Mongodb.
The steps I followed as below.

1. I created a project on mongodb.com, added a user(with role *atlasAdmin@admin*), added IP.
2. I connected it to MongoDB Compass and added the data required using compass
3. I used `connect your application` and saved below string in heroku config enviornment variable after editing username, password and dbname.

`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@vidly.5pn3u.azure.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

but it is giving error as `'MongoError: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command`

I tried below options to fix error:

1. Using mongo shell I tried to create user. I
   used string `mongo "mongodb+srv://vidly.5pn3u.azure.mongodb.net/<dbname>" --username <username>` to connect to mongo and then

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: 'admin',
    pwd: 'password',
    roles: [ { role: 'root', db: 'admin' } ]
  }
);
exit;
```

But it is giving error : `uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command`

2. on `cloud.mongodb.com` I changed a role on mongodb server to (dbAdminAnyDatabase@admin, backup@admin, readWriteAnyDatabase@admin, clusterMonitor@admin)
   but its giving same error.

Please advice how this error can be resolved?

**Edit:**

I am able to access database using mongo `connect with the mongo shell` using `show dbs` on shell (but not able to create user) and `connect using mongodb compass` and edit database in compass.
But when I try  `connect your application` option it is giving this error.

The user added has these access (dbAdminAnyDatabase@admin, backup@admin, readWriteAnyDatabase@admin, clusterMonitor@admin), even with this user its not working.

Comment: @kanagavelu-sugumar would you able to answer this please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the recent version of mongoose.
For example, you can install mongoose by using "yarn add mongoose".